# Add fixed text to Excel userform textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I would like to add additional fixed text to textbox data in specific cells in an Excel spreadsheet. For example, in the textbox the user would enter "g0/0" but in the cell A2 it should read "interface g0/0". Here is what i have so far:

```
Private Sub Populate_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Remote")
ws.Range("A2") = Interface.Value
```

So I assume i would add "interface" somewehere on that last line but i am unsure of the syntax.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to first sonstrict the required value in a string, then make that the value of "A2". Assuming your input text box is on a form...

```
Dim InterfaceValue as string
InterfaceValue = "interface" &  FormName.InputTextBox.Value
ws.Range("A2").value = InterfaceValue
```

Comment: You, my friend, are an evil genius!. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to loop all the rows, and insert fixed string value to a cell.

Ex.

for(XMLResource report: reports) {

```
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 1000);
        row.createCell(0)
                .setCellValue(report.getPage());

        row.createCell(1)
                .setCellValue(report.getTestName());

        row.createCell(2)
                .setCellValue(report.getDescription());

        row.createCell(3)
                .setCellValue(report.getSTATUS());

        row.createCell(4)
                .setCellValue(report.getBuisImpact());

        row.createCell(5)
        .setCellValue(report.getVali());
    }
```

(report is string only object)

Comment: Not sure this will work. I don't want to create cells. This is an userform to add data to an existing excel spreadsheet in specific cells to simplify building configurations

Comment: Gotcha! try row.getCell(i).setValue(YOUR VALUE), and you can update you'r excel sheet every time new data has arrived.